# .NET Dapper range

Tags: c#, orm, dapper

I have recently been running through the Dapper extension library for my API. the following code returns a list of users with their resptive addresses based on a single user id:

```
 public User GetUserBicProfiles(string userId)
    {

        using (
            var multipleResults = this.db.QueryMultiple("sp_UserPermisisons", new {userId = 
           userId},commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure))
         {
            var user = multipleResults.Read<User>().SingleOrDefault();

            var permissions= multipleResults.Read<Permissions>().ToList();

            if (user != null&& permissions != null)
            {
               user.Permissions.AddRange(permissions);
            }

            return user;
        }
    }
```

this works perfectly, but when I try and use the same set of details, but without the userId as the parameter (should return all users with their respective permissions), I get an error relating to adding the range.

System.Collections.Generic.List' does not contain a definition for 'UserPermissions' and no extension method 'UserPermissions' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The method to return all is:

```
public List<User> GetUsers()
    {
        using (var multipleResults = this.db.QueryMultiple("sp_UserPermissions",commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure))
        {
            var user = multipleResults.Read<User>().ToList();

            var permissions = multipleResults.Read<Permissions>().ToList();

            if (user != null && permissions != null)
            {

                user.Permissions.AddRange(permissions);
            }

            return user;
        }
    }
```

the User class is:

```
public class User
{
    public User()
    {
        this.Permissions = new List<Permissions>();
    }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string ApplicationName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string PasswordQuestion { get; set; }
    public string PasswordAnswer { get; set; }
    public bool? IsApproved { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastActivityDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastLoginDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastPasswordChangeDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public bool? IsOnline { get; set; }
    public bool? IsLockedOut { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastLockedOutDate { get; set; }
    public bool? FailedPasswordAttempCount { get; set; }
    public DateTime FailedPasswordAttemptWithStart { get; set; }
    public bool? FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount { get; set; }
    public DateTime FailedPasswordAnsdwerAttemptWindowStart { get; set; }


    public List<Permissions> Permissions { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the stored procedure will return something if no userId is passed in.

Comment: there is no class member called `UserPermissions`, how ever class mbr called `Permissions` is present

Comment: correction UserPermissions, should of been Permissions.

Comment: Chris, if I comment out the line where it is trying to add the range, and debug, I see the list of permissions coming back from SQL - executing the stored proc in SQL with and without param works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because you're trying to access the `Permissions` object on a `List<User>` object, which does not exist either as property or as an extensions method.

In your first example, the variable **user** is of type `User`, you return a single `User` object by using the `SingleOrDefault()` method.

```
...
var user = multipleResults.Read<User>().SingleOrDefault();

var permissions= multipleResults.Read<Permissions>().ToList();
if (user != null&& permissions != null)
{
  user.Permissions.AddRange(permissions);
}

return user; // --> user type is User
...
```

While in your second example, the variable **user** is of type `List<User>`, you return a list of `User` object (`List<User>`) using the `ToList()` method.

```
...
var user = multipleResults.Read<User>().ToList();
var permissions = multipleResults.Read<Permissions>().ToList();

if (user != null && permissions != null)
{
  user.Permissions.AddRange(permissions);
}

return user; // --> user type is List<User>
...
```

Comment: Ok, I see what your suggesting now. So, do I need to add a new instance of the class inline? List<User> etc

Comment: Yes, you're right. The problem isn't in the returned type (both `User` or `List<User>` is fine). The problem is that `Permissions` belongs to *A* `User` (each user should have its own permission list) not a list of `User`.